# Click Instantly Triggers Event Listener That Is Created By The Click

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a button with an event listener. When somebody clicks it, all content on my webpage gets replaced with something else, and a new event listener is put on the whole body of the page. However, clicking the button instantly triggers the new event listener that is only created after clicking it. Of course clicking the button also means that you clicked the body, but the new event listener is only created through the click, so I thought it wouldn't instantly trigger. I don't understand why that's happening or how to prevent it. I hope my question isn't too stupid. I'm pretty new to this whole thing and trying to teach myself the basics.

```js
$("button").on("click", () => {
  $("body").on("click", () => {
    $("body").css({"background-color": "red"});
  });
  $("body").css({"background-color": "green"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click Me</button>
```

Edited to make my point clearer. Edited again to include example. Why is the body turning red instead of green?

Comment: Please share your code if you need help with it - it's impossible to know for sure what you've coded wrong without seeing the code! However it sounds like you may be accidentally calling the function when adding the second event listener, ie doing `.addEventListener("click", someFunction())` rather than `.addEventListener("click", someFunction)`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Included example.

Comment: thanks. The problem is that you don't stop propagation of the event - the handler was getting added, then the event propagates up the body and changes the color from green to red before you see it. To fix this, add `event` as an argument to the outer "click" handler (the one on the button) and put `event.stopPropagation()` at the end of the function. I was going to put this in an answer with a working snippet but strangely when I do this the body's event handler doesn't work at all. I haven't yet been able to figure out why - but hopefully this gets you past this stage.

Comment: not sure if it's another account you've made or someone else in the same class, but in any case someone else has just asked the more or less identical question, and my suggested solution actually works there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886050/click-triggers-event-listener-that-it-creates/70886255#70886246 Don't know why it was behaving strangely here!